# cannot convert 's1*' to 's2::s1*' in assignment

Tags: c++, struct

```
struct s1 {
    int roll_no;
};

struct s2 {
    int id;
    struct s1 {
        int no;
    } *array;
};

int main(){
    s1 s1_;
    s2 s2_;
    s2_.array = &s1_;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting `[Error] cannot convert 's1*' to 's2::s1*' in assignment` when I try to compile this.

Comment: It is because `s1` is not `s2::s1`. What do you want to do?

Comment: Whoever just vandalized the tags, please pay attention - this is C++ and the C/C++ crosstagging policy [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) is "A question should be tagged with c++ only, if:  - It contains code with any C++ features. Even though the code may be "C style". - The code is compiled with a C++ compiler." This code only compiles in C++ and the compiler error is from a C++ compiler.

Comment: Not sure what "debugging details" this question needs; however, we currently have two close-voters who think otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to assign a type `s1` to a type `s2::s1`.
Even though these structs have the same name, they are not the same type. One is in the global namespace, and one is in the `s2` namespace.

And you can't have two times a struct with the same name in the same namespace.

Why not simply have

```
struct s1 {
    int roll_no;
};

struct s2 {
    int id;
    s1 *array;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code defines two *different* `s1` structures – one that is 'free-standing' and *another* that is a 'sub-class' of `s2`. Because they are different types, you cannot implicitly convert between pointers to objects of their respective types.

If you want (as it appears) there to be an `s1` pointer in your `s2` structure, then just declare it (in the `s2` definition) as a pointer to the already-defined structure:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

struct s1 {
    int roll_no;
};

struct s2 {
    int id;
    s1 *array; // Pointer to our previously-defined type
};

int main()
{
    s1 s1_;
    s2 s2_;
    s2_.array = &s1_;

    return 0;
}
```